# How to make text-align center in imagettftext()

Tags: gdlib, imagettftext

I couldn't able to get this working.

See the picture below (this is im showing in a div tag):

[image]

html code is

```
<p>t-shirt is the giveaway</p>
```

How can i achieve the same thing displayed in the image using imagettftext()

Comment: I would love to know as well.